# How to create sub pages in magento?

Tags: magento

I am working on Magento. I want to create a sub pages of cms page and sub pages will be shown in sidebar Let me know how can I do this?

I want sub pages as given in screen-shot:-  http://awesomescreenshot.com/09c5rfnr41

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to inform you that hierarchy feature is not available in Magento Community version. 
But I feel that you can achieve your requirement by using this extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/page-summary-block.html

Thanks!

Comment: please Let me know if there is any other solution for community edition.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Login to admin and navigate to CMS -> Pages.
2. Create new page.
3. Add **URL Key** as main-url/sub-url for example if your main page url is **aboutus** then sub page will be look like **aboutus/aboutus-sub**
4. To add those links to left sidebar, you should create phtml file in your theme template folder and call that phtml file from appropriate xml file.
5. <reference name="left">